# Visualforce page not working in console sidebar: id is not valid at Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, console

In my Salesforce org we currently have a custom Visualforce page implemented into the Home Page layout for creating tasks.  The extension Apex class pulls the record id from the URL and prefills the whoID portion of the task.  We are considering implementing Sales Console.  I have attempted to add this Visualforce page to the left sidebar of the Contact page of the console, however, it's giving an error:  "Id value (whatever Contact Id is in the main tab) is not valid for the Task standard controller"  Does anyone know how I might fix this issue?  Thank you!

Comment: If you include the relevant code here, it will be much easier to assist you. You may need to write a new page.

Comment: Please check my answer, hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

> If you put visualforce page which works on Classic mode and used to get `id` from URL parameter in Controller, that simple thing will not work if you use the same page as Console Sidebar component.

**Workaround**

Visualforce to be modified like this (comments have been provided in the code)

```
<apex:page id="SidebarPage" Controller="SidebarComponentController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/28.0/integration.js" />
    <!-- On window load getEnclosingPrimaryTabId() is getting called to retrieve the tabLink which will be passed to actionFunction-->
    <!-- Function has been written as in controller, getParameters().get('Id') will not work in console -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var getEnclosingPrimaryTabId = function getEnclosingPrimaryTabId() {
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(getTabLink);
        }
        var getTabLink = function getTabLink(result) {
            sforce.console.getTabLink(sforce.console.TabLink.PARENT_AND_CHILDREN,
                result.id, showTabLink);
        }
        var showTabLink = function showTabLink(result) {
            var link = result.tabLink;
            passLinkFunc(link);
        };
        window.onload = getEnclosingPrimaryTabId;
     </script>
     <apex:actionFunction name="passLinkFunc" action="{!init}" immediate="true" reRender="siteDetails">
            <apex:param id="URLString" name="URLString" assignTo="{!URLString}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

Rather than capturing URL parameter in Constructor you should parse the URL in separate method which is getting called from `actionFunction`.

```
public String queryString{get;set;}

public void init()
    {   
        System.debug('URLString=' + URLString);     
        String url = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(URLString, 'UTF-8');

        System.debug('init:url= ' + url);
        //https://cs21.salesforce.com/console#/a0lq0000001lheu&#124;/500q0000006XOZT

    }
```

Now you have to parse the following URL (sample example which I have encountered) to get the id.

> https://cs21.salesforce.com/console#/a0lq0000001lheu|/500q0000006XOZT